# Why am I not able to install the Signal app onto my Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE 5G?

Tags: installation, signal-private-messenger

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE 5G and the Signal app is seemingly unavailable for this device.

I didn't have ANY issues with Telegram, so it's quite baffling to me.

Does anyone know why? Do I need to download it from another source altogether?

Comment: There are many factors (including the ones applied by the developer themselves) that may prevent the app unavailable to install from the Play Store, and it's almost impossible to pinpoint which one specifically is the cause. On the other hand, Signal provides [alternative installation by APK](https://signal.org/android/apk/). You may want to try installing it and try it if it's working properly or not on a tablet.